# Pandas - how to remove spaces in each column in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to remove spaces, apostrophes, and double quote in each column data using this for loop

`for c in data.columns:
    data[c] = data[c].str.strip().replace(',', '').replace('\'', '').replace('\"', '').strip()`

but I keep getting this error:

`AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'strip'`

data is the data frame and was obtained from an excel file

`xl = pd.ExcelFile('test.xlsx');
data = xl.parse(sheetname='Sheet1')`

Am I missing something?  I added the `str` but that didn't help.  Is there a better way to do this.

I don't want to use the column labels, like so `data['column label']`, because the text can be different.  I would like to iterate each column and remove the characters mentioned above.

incoming data:

`id        city      country
1       Ontario       Canada
2     Calgary '        Canada'
3   'Vancouver        Canada`

desired output:

`id  city      country
1   Ontario     Canada
2   Calgary     Canada
3   Vancouver   Canada`

Comment: [DataFrame.replace()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)

Comment: @MaxU I'm not familiar with pandas, but how would you go about removing the heading/trailing spaces?

Comment: please post a sample data set and desired data set (after replacing)

Comment: @MaxU sample posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** using your sample DF:

```
In [80]: df
Out[80]:
   id         city   country
0   1      Ontario    Canada
1   2    Calgary '   Canada'
2   3  'Vancouver    Canada

In [81]: df.replace(r'[,\"\']','', regex=True).replace(r'\s*([^\s]+)\s*', r'\1', regex=True)
Out[81]:
   id       city country
0   1    Ontario  Canada
1   2    Calgary  Canada
2   3  Vancouver  Canada
```

**OLD answer:**

you can use `DataFrame.replace()` method:

```
In [75]: df.to_dict('r')
Out[75]:
[{'a': ' x,y ', 'b': 'a"b"c', 'c': 'zzz'},
 {'a': "x'y'z", 'b': 'zzz', 'c': '  ,s,,'}]


In [76]: df
Out[76]:
       a      b       c
0   x,y   a"b"c     zzz
1  x'y'z    zzz    ,s,,

In [77]: df.replace(r'[,\"\']','', regex=True).replace(r'\s*([^\s]+)\s*', r'\1', regex=True)
Out[77]:
     a    b    c
0   xy  abc  zzz
1  xyz  zzz    s
```

`r'\1'` - is a [numbered capturing RegEx group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html)

Comment: Thanks so much, this helps a lot.  One last thing, noticed there is `r'\1`, what does it actually do?

Comment: @medev21, i've added a short explanation to my answer - please chek

Answer (score 0):

data[c] does not return a value, it returns a series (a whole column of data).

You can apply the strip operation to an entire column df.apply.  You can apply the strip function this way.

Comment: @Adam_Hughes not following, where do you add `apply`? not familiar with pandas